# Using JDBC Driver for Informix + SQLException being thrown when NULL Value is encountered

Tags: jdbc, informix, sqlexception

I'm using the JDBC driver for Informix.  I connect to my host just fine, but when the query is executed a null value is returned for one of the fields specified in my select.  Instead of just retrieving that value, and SQLException gets thrown:

Column (colname) not found in any table in the query (or SLV is undefined).

I'm using the driver this way:

```
    try{
    PreparedStatement pstmtDist = conn.prepareStatement(query2);

    ResultSet rsDist = pstmtDist.executeQuery();

    while(rsDist.next()){
            int distCaseId = 0;
            String distCaseIdStr = new String();

            int distCaseDefNum = 0;
            String distCaseDefNumStr = new String();

            distCaseIdStr = rsDist.getObject("colname").toString();
            distCaseId = Integer.parseInt(distCaseIdStr.trim());

            distCaseDefNumStr = rsDist.getObject("colname2").toString();
            distCaseDefNum = Integer.parseInt(distCaseDefNumStr.trim());

            //System.out.println(String.format("distCaseId == %d  distCaseDefNum == %d\n",distCaseId,distCaseDefNum));

    }// end while district cases

    rsDist.close();
    pstmtDist.close();
    connDist.close();

    }
    catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION: "+e.getMessage());


    }
```

Any tips are welcomed!

-TU

Comment: Your question is unanswerable.  You've not shown the table schema, or the query that you are trying to prepare and execute.  The error message you cite has nothing to do with nulls; it says the query is referring to a non-existent column.  That means there is a problem with the query; syntactically, it is valid, but semantically, it is not.  To resolve that, you'll have to show the SQL and the table schema.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Your observation is correct, the error message does not point to a problem with a null value. That's the perplexing part. However, when a null value is encountered the exception is thrown. I was hoping someone had encountered this before.

I'm a public servant, and I don't think I should post that detailed db info.  The columns in my query are created in the schema.  I can run the query against the database using dbaccess and rows are retrieved, but one column has a null value--colname2.  When I remove it from the query and rerun the program the exception is not thrown.
-TU

Comment: Can you replicate it with a two column table like `CREATE TABLE x(y INTEGER, z INTEGER); INSERT INTO x(y,z) VALUES(0, 0); INSERT INTO x(y,z) VALUES(1, NULL);` and show the Java that generates the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is in line:

```
 distCaseDefNumStr = rsDist.getObject("colname2").toString();
```

and with similar lines where `getObject()` can return `null`.

If your `colname2` has `null` value then `getObject()` returns `null` and then Java tries to run `toString()` method on `null` object.

Yes, the message about column not found in result is strange, but I think that you really observe *null pointer exception*. Use `getString()` or `getInt()` methods of `ResultSet`.